# r: paste0 to print blanks in combination with seq()

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, paste

I want to print 4 blanks and 4 percentage values using `paste0` and `seq()`, but cannot get it to work.

**Expected output**

```
 ""     ""     ""     ""     "0%"   "25%"  "50%"  "75%"  "100%"
```

I tried numerous combinations, such as

```
c(paste0(rep("", 4), paste0(seq(0, 100, 25), "%")))
```

and

```
paste0(rep("", 4), seq(0, 100, 25), "%"))
```

Comment: you should close the parenthesis of paste0 after rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c(rep("", 4), paste0(seq(0, 100, 25), "%"))
#[1] ""     ""     ""     ""     "0%"   "25%"  "50%"  "75%"  "100%"
```